# Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code

Tags: php, character-encoding, soap-client

I have a strange question with PHP app connecting to a SOAP 1.2+WSDL service:

Previous information: Apache server 2.4 with php5-fcgi module.
I'm working on a client for a SOAP service, and I can do some request for the service.

The request took some time to complete. I've needed to do a set_time_limit(60) because if I doesn't have it, the script return idle timeout error:

> FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: idle
>   timeout (30 sec)

With set_time_limit, i got another different error:

> AH00524: Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 1

These error appears when I try to do the SOAP request. Without it, the page works OK.

With this error on log, I have another different error on navigator. On IE, the page doesn't load, Firefox show "Content Encoding Error" page.

These error appears if I try to show on screen the SOAP connection result (with a var_dump), and, also, if I try to do the request but doesn't send it to screen.

Trying to search for the "Content Encoding Error", I've find something about compression. I've tried to do "ob_start" before and after set_time_limit, but, when I try to do it, I get an timeout error at log (I think PHP doesn't make the timeout change), and, also, the page shows an 500 internal server error.

What's the problem? The only option I think can be getting these problem are some timeout between Apache and php5-fcgi module, but I doesn't know how to modify this for trying another option.

---

EDIT:

I have two servers on the same machine, Apache2 (2.4.10) + php5-fcgi (5.6.2) (HTTP port 80, HTTPS port 443), and Nginx (1.6.2) + php5-fcgi (HTTP port 8080).

The same page, tested with Apache2 does not work (Error described at top), on HTTP and HTTPS. Then, I try to enter with Nginx (Same webroot, theoretically same php5-fcgi config), and then, running properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the times idle timeout error when you use fastCGI is caused by a CGI request longer than the time set up with idle-timeout parameter. If not set up, the default is 30 sec.

From the [mod_fastcgi documentation](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiConfig):

> -idle-timeout n (30 seconds)
>       The number of seconds of FastCGI application inactivity allowed before the request is aborted and the event is logged (at the error
>   LogLevel). The inactivity timer applies only as long as a connection
>   is pending with the FastCGI application. If a request is queued to an
>   application, but the application doesn't respond (by writing and
>   flushing) within this period, the request will be aborted. If
>   communication is complete with the application but incomplete with the
>   client (the response is buffered), the timeout does not apply.

In log files you can see something like this:

```
[fastcgi:error] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/bin/php-fastcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://example.org/script.php
```

And in a web browser yoy get the "Content Encoding Error" message.

To avoid this error it is possible to increase the idle timeout in fastCGI configuration.

```
FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 900
```

So, by increasing idle timeout you don't need to use set_time_limit anymore.