# Getting wordpress HTTP 503 : Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 53, why?

Tags: wordpress

I am currently having a 503 error on my Wordpress website. I have already tried activating and deactivating all plug-ins to see what is causing the error, but this hasn't given me any insights. It seems the error just keeps popping up.

My error log is stating this:

> AH00524: Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 53

It seems it has something to do with the idle-timeout, but that will not provide a permanent solution - I was told.

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and what kind of fix there could be for this problem? Would really appreciate it.

Feel free to check the site out here: Housify.nl. If you do not get a 503 error right away just refresh the site a few times and you will eventually get one.

Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: Seems like an [apache error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751020/handler-for-fastcgi-script-returned-invalid-result-code)

Comment: This question is likely a better fit for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for the quick reply. I did look into that apache error and according to my hosting provider that would only temporarily fix the problem as the problem is somewhere in the site. Would you recon it's worth a try to change the idle-timeout?